# Docker Compose - Launch shell script auto after up

Tags: shell, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compsose.yml file that launch a postgis service with a shared folder of kml files. I also ave a script that can export all of those kml in my postgis database. However I would like to do so automatically after launch. How can the docker-compose read that file and run the shell command after launch ?

Thank you for the help, I am new using Docker.

```
version: '2'
services:
  postgis:
    image: mdillon/postgis
    volumes:
      - ~/test/dataPostgis:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
      - ./postgresql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - ./KML_Data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/KML_Data
    environment:
        PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
        POSTGRES_DB: db
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
  pgadmin:
    image: chorss/docker-pgadmin4
    ports:
      - 5050:5050
    volumes:
      - ~/test/dataPgadminBackUp:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
      - ./scripts/pgadmin:/tmp/scripts
    links:
      - postgis
    depends_on:
      - postgis
```

Comment: sorry.. i did not get you. do want to run a script automatically after launch?

Comment: yes ! a shell script

Comment: how were you running it before?

Comment: Well, I connect to the container and run my command/script

Comment: you can specify `command` in docker-compose file

Comment: If he specifies the command the container won't run since it will overide the starting of postgres